# How to Parse Alphavantage API response to the Class in C#

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, alpha-vantage

I am using Alphavantage API to retrieve Stock data. I am able to get data, but data is not easy to bind into class.
Below is the data I am getting from API.

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=RELIANCE.BSE&outputsize=full&apikey=demo

This is valid JSON, but I don't know how to create a class which can bind this JSON data.

Below is the CLASS I tried with, but no luck,

```
class AlphaVantageData
{
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
    public TimeSeries TimeSeries { get; set; }
}

class MetaData
{
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string Information { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
    public string LastRefreshed { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("4. Output Size")]
    public string OutputSize { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("5. Time Zone")]
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
}

class TimeSeries
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Close { get; set; }
}
```

I am using .NET core 6 framework.

Below is the sample code,

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = client.GetAsync("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=RELIANCE.BSE&outputsize=full&apikey=demo");
        var response = await request;
        var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AlphaVantageData>(json);
```

Data property have 2 objects, but both are null.

Comment: Use https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp. It will generate a nice structure for u based on JSON.

Comment: It created nice structure, but didn't bind data.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Comment: Yes, marked as true. (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using below code and it works for me.

Here is the test result.

[image]

```
    [HttpGet("test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> testAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=RELIANCE.BSE&outputsize=full&apikey=demo");
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlphaVantageData>(json);

        return Ok(data);
    }
```

**My Data class**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class aaa
    {
    }
    public class AlphaVantageData
    {
        [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
        public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Time Series (Daily)")]
        public Dictionary<string, TimeSeriesEntry> TimeSeries { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetaData
    {
        [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
        public string Information { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
        public string LastRefreshed { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("4. Output Size")]
        public string OutputSize { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("5. Time Zone")]
        public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    }

    public class TimeSeriesEntry
    {
        [JsonProperty("1. open")]
        public string Open { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("2. high")]
        public string High { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("3. low")]
        public string Low { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("4. close")]
        public string Close { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("5. adjusted close")]
        public string AdjustedClose { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("6. volume")]
        public string Volume { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("7. dividend amount")]
        public string DividendAmount { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("8. split coefficient")]
        public string SplitCoefficient { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, This worked. I don't know why I couldn't think of Dictionary way. :)